# Appery - Connect to ssh

Tags: android

I am not sure this is the right place to ask, but I will give it a shot. First of all, please note I'm not an android developer, but a php programmer.  That being said, I want to create a simple application with following functionality: connect to a server via ssh then send a list of instructions(of course, I need the response too).

I found appery.io, that helped me so far to create the interface, but I am not sure how to initiate a SSH connection. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Connectbot's source is viewable on Github. The Connection class javadocs are informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appery.io is a development environment. The app that you build simply runs in the browser, or the device (hybrid). Having said that, you can connect to any service/resource that's exposed via REST API when building an app in Appery.io